# My ggplot bar chart reorder() function isn't working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to reorder a bar chart into descending order (with the the roadgroup  with the highest contact rate at the top). However the reorder() function doesn't seem to be working.

```
    for (i in uniq_wards) 
  { print(ggplot(data = subset(roads, Ward == i),
               aes(x = reorder(Roadgroup, Contact.rate),
                   y = Contact.rate,
                   fill = undecided_rate)) +
          geom_col() +
          coord_flip() +
          labs(fill = "Undecided rate", y = "Contact Rate", x = "Road Group") +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
                text = element_text(size = 8)) +
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "blue", limits=c(0.0, 0.35)) +
          ggtitle(i, subtitle = "Contact Rate and Undecided Density")) 
  }
```

[Example ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxQ5f.png)

The second image is an example of the descending order that I want the 1st plot to look like, which uses the same variable axis reorder() code:

```
x = reorder(Roadgroup, Contact.rate),
                   y = Contact.rate,
```

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUffd.png)

Comment: welcome to SO. Please have a read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're much more likely to get answers

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without data. You could try the following. I only added `FUN = sum` to your original code. If it does not work, please provide some example data.

```
library(tidyverse) 
    for (i in uniq_wards) 
  { print(ggplot(data = subset(roads, Ward == i),
               aes(x = reorder(Roadgroup, Contact.rate, FUN = sum),
                   y = Contact.rate,
                   fill = undecided_rate)) +
          geom_col() +
          coord_flip() +
          labs(fill = "Undecided rate", y = "Contact Rate", x = "Road Group") +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
                text = element_text(size = 8)) +
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "blue", limits=c(0.0, 0.35)) +
          ggtitle(i, subtitle = "Contact Rate and Undecided Density")) 
  }
```